# Transform Sequence of Maps into Map of Keys to Sequences of Values in Scala

Tags: scala, transformation

I'm trying to turn a sequence of maps, like for instance

```
val input = Seq(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2),
                Map("a" -> 10,  "c" -> 30),
                Map("b" -> 200, "c" -> 300, "d" -> 400))
```

into a map from the keys in those maps to the sequence of values they map to across each of the maps in the original sequence.

So the above should transform into

```
val output = Map("a" -> Seq(1, 10),
                 "b" -> Seq(2, 200),
                 "c" -> Seq(30, 300),
                 "d" -> Seq(400))
```

I can think of a few ways to go about this but I'm looking for a solution that is idiomatic or the best scala style for this sort of transformation? Ideally without being really wasteful but performance isn't a great concern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val output = input.flatten.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

It will first flatten your map into a `Seq` of all map entries. Then it groups the map entries on their keys. Finally, you map the values (which is now a list of map entries) to a list of map-values.

Comment: You can just use `flatten` rather than `flatMap(_.toSeq)`

Comment: @Tim Oh, that's true. Fixed.